# Community: different landing pages for different portal profiles?

Tags: profile, portal, customer-community, landing-page

I have a client using Customer Portal licenses with Community.  They have two profiles for customer portal users.  They want a different landing page (Visualforce page) for each profile.

I've been searching around and can't figure out how to set this.  The community Tabs and Pages page doesn't allow profile-specific settings.  I have read about using a custom App with a specific landing page and assigned to a profile, but that seems to be available only for standard user licenses, not portal licenses.

Any suggestions?

Thanks
David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could configure this (never displayed page) as the landing page:

```
<apex:page controller="RedirectController" action="{!redirect}"/>
```

where its controller makes the decision about which page to display:

```
public with sharing class RedirectController {
    public PageReference redirect() {
        // Query the profile ids
        // Return the appropriate landing page
        if (UserInfo.getProfileId() == ...) {
            return Page.LandingPageA;
        } else {
            return Page.LandingPageB;
        }
    }
}
```